# Solving matrix equation A B = C. with B(n* 1) and C(n *1)

Tags: python, matrix, equation-solving

I am trying to solve a matrix equation such as `A.B = C`. The A is the unknown matrix and i must find it. 
I have `B(n*1)` and `C(n*1)`, so `A` must be `n*n`.

I used the `BT* A.T =C.T` method (`numpy.linalg.solve(B.T, C.T)`).
But it produces an error:

> LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square.

So the problem is that B isn't square.

Comment: are both `A` and `B` vectors with one column? If so, then there's no possible solution (you need more variables, specifcally you need `A` to be a square matrix).

Comment: You have two `n`-dimensional vectors and you're trying to solve for an `n`-by-`n` matrix? Unless `n` is 1 or `A` is the zero vector, that's underspecified and there are infinitely many correct answers.

Comment: Sorry, i changed the question to be more correct.@Barranka @Tanner Swett

Comment: The "problem" is that your equation has infinitely many solutions. Do you just want an arbitrary solution or do you need a *good* solution? What are you trying to accomplish by solving this equation?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little example for you:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
b = np.array([5, 6])
x = np.linalg.solve(a, b)

print "A={0}".format(a)
print "B={0}".format(b)
print "x={0}".format(x)
```

For more information, please read the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html#numpy.linalg.solve)

Comment: the problem that a isn't square

Comment: This solves for one of the vectors. OP asked how to solve for the matrix (which doesn't seem very useful but that was the question).

Comment: @interjay OP edited the question changing the meaning... this one was a good one few hours ago

Comment: OP changed the variable names, but the question still specified that the input is two vectors and the output is a matrix.

Comment: @interjay I see, well, then I misunderstood the question

Answer (score 0):

If you're solving for the matrix, there is an infinite number of solutions (assuming that `B` is nonzero). Here's one of the possible solutions:

Choose an nonzero element of `B`, `Bi`. Now construct a matrix `A` such that the `i`th column is `C / Bi`, and the other columns are zero.

It should be easy to verify that multiplying this matrix by `B` gives `C`.